# Does incense stack in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Are we able to use more than one incense at the same time? Do they stack? If so how, do more Pokemon come in 30mins or does the duration increase?

Comment: Try using 2 at the same tie and provide the answer here ;-)

Comment: @RomainFournereau I would if I had lots of incense, too bad I don't :(

Comment: While I cannot be sure, I think they won't stack. Worst case scenario, they replace each other.

Comment: Is that the royal "We" or do you mean you and your friends?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Incense does not stack. Like lucky eggs, you are prevented from using a second while a first is active. "You've already applied this type of enhancement."